# How to know the change in content of an xml file using Node.js

Tags: node.js, xml-parsing

My problem is: I am having data in an xml file with url "http://XXXXX.xml" and this file will be updated with a new record atleast for every 2 minutes. I need to know whenever a new record was created in that file using "Node.js", and I need to make some "updates" on the client side using that record immediately.

Can anyone please tell me the process to know when the "xml" file at a specific url was modified using node.js.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can read for yourself here: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs.watch